# datatables with ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am working on event management site where i've to send emails and show the read, unread, bounced back...etc status email address in modal box. Showing the email addresses in modal box is working fine. I want to add datatables to it. When i Load the modal box first time it is showing the pagination but when i click on second time there is datatables error. Can Anyone help me in this please? Below is my code:-

```
$("body").on("click", ".textcontent", function(){
    var option = $(this).attr("option");
    var campaign_id = $("#campaign").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_emaillist.php",
        data: { option : option, campaign_id : campaign_id },
        success: function (resp){
            $("#emailslist").html(resp);
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        }
    });
});
```

Below is the response from ajax

```
<?php 
    $option = $_REQUEST["option"];
    $campaign_id = $_REQUEST["campaign_id"];
    $emaillist = $gnrl->emaillist($campaign_id,$option);
    $totalemail = count($emaillist);
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="agent-profile">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
                <div class="modal fade modelbx" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 20px;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $option." Users List"; ?></h4>
                                <?php if($totalemail){ ?>
                                    <a href="exportuserslist.php?campid=<?php echo $campaign_id; ?>&opt=<?php echo $option; ?>" class="exportuser" style="float: right; font-size: 20px; margin: -26px 40px 0 0;">Export Users</a>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <?php if(isset($campaign_id) && $campaign_id != "" && $campaign_id != "0"){ ?>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Event Name</label><hr>
                                        <div><span class="emaillist"><?php echo $campaigntitle = $dclass->select("tbl_campaign","campaignsubject","id = :id",array("id" => $campaign_id)); ?></span></div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } if($option == "Nominated" && $totalemail > 0){ ?>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <table border="1" id="statstable">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Nominated By User</th>
                                                    <th>Nominated User Name</th>
                                                    <th>Email</th>
                                                    <th>Company</th>
                                                    <th>Contact Number</th>
                                                    <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php
                                                    if(isset($campaign_id) && $campaign_id != "0"){
                                                        $nominateduid = $dclass->select("tbl_nominateusers n left join tbl_user u on n.user_id = u.id","n.id,n.user_id,u.emailaddress"," AND n.campaign_id = '$campaign_id'"); 
                                                    }else{
                                                        $nominateduid = $dclass->select("tbl_nominateusers n left join tbl_user u on n.user_id = u.id","n.id,n.user_id,u.emailaddress"); 
                                                    }
                                                    foreach($nominateduid as $value){
                                                        $nominid = $value["id"];
                                                        if(isset($campaign_id) && $campaign_id != "0"){
                                                            $selcond = " AND campaign_id = '$campaign_id' AND id = '$nominid'";
                                                        }else{
                                                            $selcond = " AND user_id = '{$value["user_id"]}' AND id = '$nominid'";
                                                        }
                                                        $emaildet = $dclass->select("tbl_nominateusers","*",$selcond);
                                                ?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                if($value["user_id"] == 0){
                                                                    if(isset($campaign_id) && $campaign_id != "0"){
                                                                        $nominatedemailaddress = $dclass->select("tbl_emailusers","useremail","campaign_id = :campaign_id AND user_id = :user_id",array("campaign_id" => $campaign_id, "user_id" => 0));    
                                                                    }else{
                                                                        $nominatedemailaddress = $dclass->select("tbl_emailusers","useremail","user_id = :user_id",array("user_id" => 0));    
                                                                    }
                                                                }else{ 
                                                                    $nominatedemailaddress = $value["emailaddress"];
                                                                }
                                                                echo $nominatedemailaddress;
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                if(isset($emaildet[0]["nominatename"]) && $emaildet[0]["nominatename"] != ""){
                                                                    echo $emaildet[0]["nominatename"];
                                                                }else{
                                                                    echo "---"; 
                                                                } 
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                if($totalemail > 0){
                                                                    echo $emaildet[0]["useremails"];
                                                                }else{
                                                                    echo "There is No $option Email"; 
                                                                } 
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                if(isset($emaildet[0]["companyname"]) && $emaildet[0]["companyname"] != ""){
                                                                    echo $emaildet[0]["companyname"];
                                                                }else{
                                                                    echo "---"; 
                                                                } 
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                if(isset($emaildet[0]["contactnumber"]) && $emaildet[0]["contactnumber"] != ""){
                                                                    echo $emaildet[0]["contactnumber"];
                                                                }else{
                                                                    echo "---"; 
                                                                } 
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                if(isset($emaildet[0]["mobilenumber"]) && $emaildet[0]["mobilenumber"] != ""){
                                                                    echo $emaildet[0]["mobilenumber"];
                                                                }else{
                                                                    echo "---"; 
                                                                } 
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <table border="1" id="statstable">
                                            <thead><tr><th>Email Address</th></tr></thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php 
                                                    if($totalemail > 0){
                                                        foreach($emaillist as $emails){ 
                                                ?>
                                                    <tr><td><?php echo $emails; ?></td></tr>
                                                <?php } }else{ ?>
                                                    <tr><td><?php echo "There is No $option Email"; ?></td></tr>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .modal.fade.in{ top: 10%!important; }
    img{ max-width: 125%!important; }
    .modal-dialog{ width: 900px!important; }
    .modal .modal-body{ max-height: 420px; overflow-y: auto; }
    .modal{ width: auto!important; }
    .carttable, .carttable td{ padding: 5px; }
    .modelbx{ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/login-main-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0; bottom: 0; display: none; left: 0; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999999 !important; }
    .sbbtn{ background-color: green; border: 0!important; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; height: 35px; width: 90px; }
    .alert-success{ color: #3c763d; background-color: #dff0d8; border-color: #d6e9c6; }
    .alert{ padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; }
    .textcontent{ float: left; width:100%; color: #5C9BD5; }
    .emaillist{ color: #5698D4; line-height: 30px; margin: 10px; }
    td, th{ padding: 10px!important; }
    #statstable{ margin-bottom: 20px!important; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#statstable").dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[0,"desc"]]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: I m getting this error TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Comment: have you inlcuded jquery files of datatable?

Comment: Yes, The datatable is loading first time, but when i click second time it is showing me error as TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Comment: where is your datatable.js included in your code?

Comment: it is included in my main php file from where i am calling ajax

Comment: Include  datatable.js file in get_emaillist.php after jquery.min.js

Comment: Not working. Showing error as TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Answer (score 0):

When you charge new elements with ajax, the javascript code doesn´t know those new elements. Maybe you can try recalling the data-tables init in the success section of the ajax call.